# Cannot set model MVC property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to set a Profile Property (ComplexID) through the standard Account controller code that comes with the standard MVC3 template. I am using a autocomplete widget from the jquery library to set the value of a hidden field when a value is selected from the autocomplete. The setter is confirmed by an alert I added, but when I try to save the textbox values, I get an error from the Model.IsValid saying the the ComplexID needs to be set. In the Account Model, I have set the ComplexID field as [Required]. What am I doing wrong?  Thanks

```
<div>
 <input type="text" name="q" id="complexes" />
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ComplexID, new { id="complexid"})
</div>
```

and the Jscript is:

```
    $("#complexes").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
     $.ajax({
     url: "/Account/QuickSearch", type: "POST", dataType: "json",
     data: { query: request.term },
            success: function(data) {
                response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return { label: item.Name + " , " + item.Address1, value: item.Name, id: item.ComplexID };
                }))
            }
        })

    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {

        var selecteditem = ui.item;
        $("#complexid").text(selecteditem.id);
        alert(ui.item ? ("You picked '" + selecteditem.label + "' and the hidden textbox now has a value of " + $("#complexid").text()) : "Nothing selected");            
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$("#complexid").text(selecteditem.id);
```

on

```
$("#complexid").val(selecteditem.id);
```